# how to disable excel interaction completely when any modal box is open

Tags: python, excel, vba, excel-formula

Hii I am working on a excel addin which has a custom UI box . so I want to disable interaction with excel until the UI box does not close. As you can see below in the attached image when the COM Addins box is open the interaction with excel is disabled . so how can we achieve this although my addin is in python using pyxll any vba solutions or any other language solutions will also be acceptable.

[image]

Comment: Why have you tagged Python, C# AND VBA?

Comment: I'm removing your C# tag because this very clearly has nothing to do with C#. You say your add-in is in Python, and you want to do this in VBA. OK....maybe. But this has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: So you're asking how to show a model window in VBA? e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/show-method

Comment: well I want the excel interaction to be disabled when such model window shows up

Comment: well the behaviour represented in the image where the excel interaction is totally disabled when the com addin box is open is something I want

Comment: referenced c# and python because "any solution will be acceptable", no?

Comment: "until the UI box does not close." - what does this mean? indefinitely, or do you mean the opposite "until it closes"??

Comment: so there is a cross(x) on the top right corner of box and user can close the box when he clicks on it. So the statement "until the UI box does not close" means that until user is not done with his work on the UI box the excel interaction will stay disabled

Comment: @James you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
Sub test():
    Application.Interactive = False
    '(optional code here ->) Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    '(optional code here ->) Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Application.Interactive = True
End Sub
```

Ta,

J

Comment: Hey @james this works fantastically well and fits my solution. Thank you you are a life saver

Comment: Any time buddy.